# quicksand jquery: limit items shown

Tags: javascript, jquery

a similar question from awhile ago without an answer: [Limit items or paginate in Quicksand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8264705/quicksand-js-limit-items-or-paginate)

seems to be in popular demand, but have been searching to no avail. anyone able to accomplish this?

example html:

```
<ul class="quicksand_list"> 
    <li data-value="#all"><a href="#">All</a></li>
    <li data-value="#fruits"><a href="#">Fruits</a></li>
    <li data-value="#vegetables"><a href="#">Vegetables</a></li>        
</ul>
```

it filters to all by default, i know i could do a filter on page load but that's not effective... just trying to limit the amount shown on a landing page when there's 300+ items

Comment: I am not sure if there is anything ready to use, but you can try to develop a combination of any jQuery pagination plugin and quicksand.

Comment: Don't want pagination... just a limit for the #all filter.

Comment: @elzi, the only thing quickSand does is the animation. Basically what you need is Ajax-loaded data. instead of "All" items you just provide "Top 50" items or smth like this. Ajax example is here: http://razorjack.net/quicksand/demos/ajax.html